# AngularJS - Disabling checkbox on button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have the following scenario:
I have a set of checkboxes which are disabled by default.  Now, on clicking button 1, I need the checkboxes to be enabled and also show buttons 2 & 3 and hide button 1 at that point.

On clicking on buttons 2 or 3, I need to disable the checkboxes again and show button 1 while hiding buttons 2 & 3.

I am new to AngularJS, and although I have tried with ng-Click and ng-Disabled, I have not managed to achieve what I need.  Here is a sample of what I have so far:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<button ng-model="!clicked" ng-show="!clicked">Button 1</button>
<button ng-model="clicked" ng-show="clicked">Button 2</button>
<button ng-model="clicked" ng-show="clicked">Button 3</button>


<div>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 3
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 4
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 5

</div>
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Please check working example - http://plnkr.co/edit/niAmt0kfJyfAOYeEbVqL?p=preview

HTML

```
<button ng-show="clicked" ng-click="clicked = !clicked">Button 1</button>
<button ng-show="!clicked" ng-click="clicked = !clicked">Button 2</button>
<button ng-show="!clicked" ng-click="clicked = !clicked">Button 3</button>


<div>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 3
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 4
  <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="clicked">Checkbox 5

</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.clicked = true;
});
```

Comment: Try to give a small but working example with a controller declaration. Also consider using controllerAs-syntax instead of $scope, especially when helping enwer developers, as $scope is outdated for that use case

Comment: Value of clicked is  initially set to true at that point, in the case button 1 and checkboxes are shown and disabled respectively. When we click on button 1 just clicked is set to false in this case button 1 is hidden and other button was displayed and checkboxes are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Write a `controller` to handle the buttons and provide the disabled condition for the checkboxes. Controllers should handle the view logic, not the view itself.

**Controller**(mycontroller.js):

```
angular.module("myApp")
.controller("MyController", function() {
    var self = this;

    self.checkboxesEnabled = false;

    self.enableBoxes = function() {
        self.checkboxesEnabled = true;
    }

    self.disableBoxes = function() {
        self.checkboxesEnabled = false;
    }
});
```

**Page**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="mycontroller.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as my">
    <button ng-show="!my.checkboxesEnabled" ng-click="my.enableBoxes">Button 1</button>
    <button ng-show="my.checkboxesEnabled" ng-click="my.disableBoxes">Button 2</button>
    <button ng-show="my.checkboxesEnabled" ng-click="my.disableBoxes">Button 3</button>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!my.checkboxesEnabled">Checkbox 1
      <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!my.checkboxesEnabled">Checkbox 2
      <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!my.checkboxesEnabled">Checkbox 3
      <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!my.checkboxesEnabled">Checkbox 4
      <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="!my.checkboxesEnabled">Checkbox 5
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

page;

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<input    type="checkbox"   ng-disabled="checkMe"    />Toggles
<button ng-click="check()">disable/enable</button></div>
```

controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.checkMe=false;
    $scope.check = function() {
    $scope.checkMe=!$scope.checkMe;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider using controllerAs-syntax instead of $scope, especially when helping people that are new to angular.

Comment: @LionC I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the usage of ng-model. Check out the Angular docs for all the directives, they are quite straight-forward.

Find a working example of what you want here : http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/hb7lu/

```
<button ng-show="checkboxesDisabled" ng-click="checkboxesDisabled = !checkboxesDisabled">Button 1</button>
<button ng-hide="checkboxesDisabled" ng-click="checkboxesDisabled = !checkboxesDisabled">Button 2</button>
<button ng-hide="checkboxesDisabled" ng-click="checkboxesDisabled = !checkboxesDisabled">Button 3</button>


<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="checkboxesDisabled">Checkbox 1
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="checkboxesDisabled">Checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="checkboxesDisabled">Checkbox 3
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="checkboxesDisabled">Checkbox 4
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="checkboxesDisabled">Checkbox 5

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dCBfwaIFTblauWUL7fBv?p=preview) is a working plunker for your scenario. You do not need to use ng-model on button. It won't do anything there. Plus, IMO checkBoxDisabled as a name makes more sense for the model. There are a couple of more changes that I have done to make it work.

```
  <button ng-click="vm.toggleDisable()" ng-show="vm.checkBoxDisabled">Button 1</button>
  <button ng-click="vm.toggleDisable()" ng-show="!vm.checkBoxDisabled">Button 2</button>
  <button ng-click="vm.toggleDisable()" ng-show="!vm.checkBoxDisabled">Button 3</button>


  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="vm.checkBoxDisabled">Checkbox 1
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="vm.checkBoxDisabled">Checkbox 2
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="vm.checkBoxDisabled">Checkbox 3
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="vm.checkBoxDisabled">Checkbox 4
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="vm.checkBoxDisabled">Checkbox 5

  </div>
```

Controller:-

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller('MyController', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.checkBoxDisabled = false;
  vm.toggleDisable = function() {
    vm.checkBoxDisabled = !vm.checkBoxDisabled;
  }
})
```

EDIT: As LionC suggested, you should ideally put your logic in controller. I have updated my answer and plunker accordingly.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there something wrong with the solution? It would be great if you could leave a comment on why you are downvoting.